# Clear a character on screen with ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

My program currently allows the user to draw the $ character on the screen with ncurses initialized when a key is pressed.

```
    mvaddch(y,x,'$');
```

I also have a box drawn and I want to say that after the user presses a specific key, I want the $ to be erased and placed in the new position the user puts it without erasing the entire screen. I tried using erase(), but after that it would erase the entire screen and I don't want that. I want it to keep the box that was drawn. So how would I do this?

Comment: Draw a space character over the `'$'`?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to approach this is to create *windows* on the screen, e.g., with [newwin](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html) or subwin, and create the box and '$' in different windows while using [clear](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_clear.3x.html)/wclear to clear the appropriate places on the screen.

Keep in mind that [getch](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html)/wgetch does a refresh on the window with which it is associated, so that may overwrite updates from overlapping windows.